# Can,t upload file Using Webapi - .NET6- localhost port not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am trying to upload a file using webapi (.NET6 ). There is no errors in the code . But warnings are there.I have getting below messge in terminal when I run the .csproj file.

**warning CS8618: Non-nullable property 'files' must contain a non-null value
when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.**

While I runs, Getting this message and running stops. Warning shows in fileModel.cs at *files*

I have tried putting **IFormFile?**. still showing warnings and not runs.

I'm Using **VS Code**. wwwroot folder is created.

My file model:

fileModel.cs

```
{
    public class fileModel
    {
       public  IFormFile files {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Controller file
FilesController.cs

```
  public class FilesController : ControllerBase
  {

    [HttpPost]
    public string UploadFile(fileModel objFile)
    {
      try
      {
        if (objFile.files.Length > 0)
        {
          UploadFile(objFile);
          return "Upload" + objFile.files.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
          return "Failed";
        }
      }
      catch (System.Exception ex)
      {

        return ex.Message.ToString();
      }

    }
  }
```

Interface & Implementation:

IFileUpload.cs:

```
    public interface IFileUpload
    {
        public void UploadFile(fileModel formFile);
    }
```

FileUpload.cs

```
public class FileUpload : IFileUpload
    {
        private IWebHostEnvironment environment;
        public FileUpload(IWebHostEnvironment _enviornment)
        {
            environment = _enviornment;
        }

        //
        public void UploadFile(fileModel formFile){

            if (!Directory.Exists(environment.WebRootPath + "\\Uploads"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(environment.WebRootPath + "\\Uploads");
            }

            using(FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(environment.WebRootPath + "\\Uploads"+formFile.files.FileName)){

                formFile.files.CopyTo(fileStream);
                fileStream.Flush();
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to debug the code? How are you calling this API? What response do you get when you call the API?

Comment: Is you controller at client or server?   There are 5 steps when using a controller 1) Client send a request with a POST.  The Post indicates the request contains a body.  If you do not have a body user GET 2) Sever receives request with GET 3) Server processes the request 4) Server send a Response with Post 5) Client receives Response with GET.  Often I see code that incorrectly uses httpGet and httpPost.  Controllers can be used either at client or server, but sample code doesn't clearly indicate if the controller is at client or server.

Comment: The error indicates you have a constructor "public FileUpload(IWebHostEnvironment _enviornment)" and the upload is missing the body which is the parameter of the constructor.  Probably the error is due to the httpPost  should be a httpGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While I runs, Getting this message and running stops. Warning shows in
> fileModel.cs at files.

Well, its pretty obvious that it will stop suddenly because you haven't initialize your `IFileUpload interface` into your `controller class` therefore, it will certainly break the execution. You ought to write that in following manners:

**Controller With Constructor:**

```
public class FilesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IFileUpload _fileUplaod;

        public FilesController(IFileUpload fileUplaod)
        {
            _fileUplaod = fileUplaod;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UploadFile(fileModel objFile)
        {
            try
            {
                if (objFile.files.Length > 0)
                {
                    _fileUplaod.UploadFile(objFile);
                    return Ok("Upload" + objFile.files.FileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok("Failed");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

                return Ok(ex.Message.ToString());
            }

        }
        
    }
```

**Program.cs**

You must register above `interface` on your `program.cs` file as following

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFileUpload, FileUpload>();
```

**Output**

[image]

**Execution Debugging Result:**

[image]